# SwiftUI: Replace onEditingChanged in TextField with FocusState

Tags: swiftui

According to the official Apple developer documentation, the `init(_:text:onEditingChanged:onCommit:)` for a `TextField` is deprecated now: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:text:oneditingchanged:oncommit:)-6lnin

So far I still can use:

```
TextField("placeholder", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { _ in print("focus changed") })
```

But I don't understand how to replace the `onEditingChanged` with the new `FocusState` as suggested in the developer documentation. Any hints how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by observing changes to the focus state in an `onChange` block. The block will be passed the new focus state, and you can use a capture list to capture the old state. For example, if you wanted to know when the user has finished editing a field so that you could perform validation, you could do this:

```
struct URLForm: View {
    enum Field {
        case name, url
    }
    @FocusState private var focus: Field?
    @State private var name: String
    @State private var urlPath: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .focused($focus, equals: .name)
            .onChange(of: focus) { [oldFocus = focus] newFocus in
                guard oldFocus == .name, newFocus != .name else { return }
                // user has finished editing this field
            }
        
        TextField("URL", text: $urlPath)
            .focused($focus, equals: .url)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I was searching for. A little bit inconvinient, but it works :)